# MVC 4 posting with POST method doesn't work (with GET method - works)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is my model:

```
public class LoginModel {
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller header:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(
        LoginModel model
    )
```

This is my view:

```
 <form action="@Url.Action("Login", "Login")" method="GET">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ReturnUrl)
        User name: @Html.TextBoxFor(f=>f.username)
        <br />
        Password: @Html.PasswordFor(f=>f.password)
        <br /><br />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```

When I change the method on the form from "GET" to "POST" the binding doesn't work.
I tried to add:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST", "GET")]
```

to the controller header, it doesn't help

Comment: do you have only a single action method for both GET and POST ?

Comment: Yes, is that not possible?

Answer (score 3):

Be carefull , `ActionResult Login` is not your controller... it is your Action, add this in the header of your action:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
  // your code
  return View("NameofView"); //**UPDATE
}
```

and your form:

```
method="POST"
```

UPDATE*

See that you can explicitly set the name of the view in the return clause.
And if your POST is calling your Login Action it is because you put it explicitly in the action attribute inside your form definition.

```
<form action="<Here_your_action>" method="POST">
```

If you want to do both "actions" for GET and POST, you must code two forms to match this definition.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer,
I need this action to work with both get and post methods. Not possible?

Comment: @Shahar, I never used them together and i dont know if this is posible but always is a best practice divide responsabilities, but if you reuse the Action for Get purposes you are passing a null object as a parameter and if you want maintain this code in the future it will turn unmanageable. I recommend that you divide into a separate GET and POST.

Comment: When I seperate them, every request is redirecting to the Login action (which returns the view with the user & password inputs). I added to the [AllowAnonymous] to the new check method, but it still goes there.
Maybe a problem with the web.config configuration? here it is: <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" timeout="2880" />
      </authentication>

Comment: If you dont write the name of view that you are returning and do only `return View();` the framework (for convention) it will search and try to return a View with the same name of the action, in this case Login View.

Comment: Every request goes to the "Login" action because this is what I defined on the web.config. The form is submitted to "LoginCheck", but because I didn't complete the login it goes again to the "Login" Action.

Comment: Try to code this at the end of your action `return View("YourViewName");`

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxForm(model => model.MyField)
}
```

And, as Max said, use `return View();` in your Action.